# /tools/build/Build.include: No such file or directory while compiling

Tags: rhel, kernel, kernel-modules, make

I am trying to compile kernel module 4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64. On running make prepare getting the following error

```
  DESCEND  objtool
/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.build:37: /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Build.include: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Build.include'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:43: /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.include:4: fixdep] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:65: objtool] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1672: tools/objtool] Error 2
```

There is no Build.include file to be present. I have tried installing different source kernel dev packages. get the same error for this version all the time. What could be the reason?